# Make Certificate Visible to user after user meets target

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am having problem wrapping my head around this problem.

If you run the query embedded in code below, it shows Total Questions (TotalQuestions) asked, Total Correct (TotalCorrect2) and percentage correct (PercentCorrect2).

We have students who participate in video tutorials.

After each lesson, they are given quizzes, a total of 30 questions.

To pass through each segment of the tutorials, a student must score at least 80% of the quizzes.

The code below is calculating Total questions, total correct and percentage correct.

Here is where I am having issues.

If a student answers all 30 questions AND gets 80% or more of the questions correct, a certificate is exposed to the student so s/he can print his or her certificate.

If both criteria is not met, the certificate stays hidden from the student.

I am having difficulty with the IF portion of this task.

For instance,

```
if totalQuestions = 30 and percentCorrect2 >= 80 then

  btnGetUser.Visible = True

else

 btnGetUser.Visible = False

end if

This above is not working.
```

When I run the code, and a particular user meets the condition of the IF statement, the certificate is supposed to be exposed. It does so when I run it in SSMS.

So far, the certificate has remained hidden even though I am testing with users who have taken and passed the tests and have made the conditions.

When I debug the code, I can see that totalQuestions shows 30 which is correct but the rest show 0.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

```
Dim s As String = ";WITH Questions AS " & _
       " ( SELECT SQ.QuestionID, " & _
         "   CorrectChoices = COUNT(NULLIF(SC.IsCorrect, 0)), " & _
        "    ChoicesGiven = COUNT(SA.ChoiceID), " & _
       "     CorrectChoicesGiven = COUNT(CASE WHEN SA.ChoiceID IS NOT NULL AND SC.IsCorrect = 1 THEN 1 END), " & _
       "     ExtraChoicesGiven = CASE WHEN COUNT(SA.ChoiceID) > COUNT(NULLIF(SC.IsCorrect, 0)) THEN COUNT(SA.ChoiceID) - COUNT(NULLIF(SC.IsCorrect, 0)) ELSE 0 END " & _
        "  FROM SurveyQuestions SQ " & _
        "  INNER JOIN SurveyChoices SC " & _
        "  ON SQ.QuestionId = SC.QuestionID " & _
        "  LEFT JOIN SurveyAnswers SA " & _ 
        "  ON SA.QuestionId = SC.QuestionID  " & _
        "  AND SA.ChoiceID = SC.ChoiceID " & _
        "  AND SA.UserName = @username " & _
        "  GROUP BY SQ.QuestionID " & _
        " ), QuestionScores AS " & _
        "   (SELECT QuestionID, " & _
        "     Score = CASE WHEN CorrectChoicesGiven - ExtraChoicesGiven < 0 THEN 0 " & _
        "             ELSE CAST(CorrectChoicesGiven - ExtraChoicesGiven AS FLOAT) / CorrectChoices " & _
        "             END, " & _
        "     Score2 = ISNULL(CAST(CorrectChoicesGiven AS FLOAT) / NULLIF(CASE WHEN ChoicesGiven > CorrectChoices THEN ChoicesGiven ELSE CorrectChoices END, 0), 0) " & _
        "    FROM Questions " & _
        "   )
         "   SELECT TotalQuestions = COUNT(*), " & _
         "    TotalCorrect = SUM(Score), " & _
         "    PercentCorrect = CAST(100.0 * SUM(Score) / COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)), " & _
         "    TotalCorrect2 = SUM(Score2), " & _
          "   PercentCorrect2 = CAST(100.0 * SUM(Score2) / COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) " & _
          "  FROM QuestionScores;"

Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(s, conn)

Dim TotalQuestions As Integer
Dim TotalCorrect As Double
Dim TotalPercent As Decimal
Dim TotalCorrect2 As Double
Dim TotalPercent2 As Decimal

conn.Open()
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text)
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

If reader.Read() Then
    TotalQuestions = reader.GetInt32(0)
    TotalCorrect = reader.GetDouble(1)
    TotalPercent = reader.GetDecimal(2)
    TotalCorrect2 = reader.GetDouble(3)
    TotalPercent2 = reader.GetDecimal(4)
End If
reader.Close()
conn.Close()
If TotalQuestions = 30 and TotalPercent2 >= 80 Then
    btnGetUser.Visible = True
Else
    btnGetUser.Visible = False
End If
```